# Mysql command select from id to id for search

Tags: php, mysql

what im trying to do is to select the videos from my database what the VID = 1 and max VID = 25000, i have 400k videos but i don't want to start them all so i need to select this way, i make this command for the searching script but how i see its not working ... hope someone can help me with this problem

MySql command for searching (this command is to show me how many videos found):

```
  select 
  count(*) as num 
  from 
    video 
 where 
    VID BETWEEN 1 AND 25000 
 AND 
    title LIKE '%key1%' 
 or 
    title LIKE '%key2%' 
 or 
    title LIKE '%key3%' 
 or 
    title LIKE '%key4%'
```

Comment: Try: select count(*) as num from video where VID BETWEEN 1 AND 25000 AND (title LIKE '%key1%' or title LIKE '%key2%' or title LIKE '%key3%' or title LIKE '%key4%')

Comment: i have added my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your `LIKE` in parenthesis (), try doing:

```
select count(some_id) as num from video where 
VID >= 1 AND VID <= 25000 AND 
(title LIKE '%key1%' or title LIKE '%key2%' or title LIKE '%key3%' or title LIKE '%key4%')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the operator precedence by adding bracket to the AND clause

```
   select 
    count(*) as num 
    from 
        video 
    where 
        VID BETWEEN 1 AND 25000 
    AND 
        (title LIKE '%key1%' 
    or 
        title LIKE '%key2%' 
    or 
        title LIKE '%key3%' 
    or 
        title LIKE '%key4%' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
select count(*) as num from video where VID BETWEEN 1 AND 25000 AND (title LIKE '%key1%' or title LIKE '%key2%' or title LIKE '%key3%' or title LIKE '%key4%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just all title comparison set in bracket.

```
select 
  count(*) as num 
  from 
    video 
 where 
    VID BETWEEN 1 AND 25000 
 AND (
    title LIKE '%key1%' 
 or 
    title LIKE '%key2%' 
 or 
    title LIKE '%key3%' 
 or 
    title LIKE '%key4%' 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SELECT count(title) as num 
 FROM video 
 WHERE vid <= 25000 
 AND (title LIKE '%key1%' OR title LIKE '%key2%' OR title LIKE '%key3%' OR title LIKE '%key4%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your between is doing just fine, the real problem is that your current script is executed like this, because AND operator has higher precedence than OR:

```
select 
count(*) as num 
from 
  video 
where 
  (VID BETWEEN 1 AND 25000 
AND 
  title LIKE '%key1%')
or 
  title LIKE '%key2%' 
or 
  title LIKE '%key3%' 
or 
  title LIKE '%key4%'
```

So what you need to do is change it like this:

```
select 
count(*) as num 
from 
  video 
where 
  VID BETWEEN 1 AND 25000 
AND (
  title LIKE '%key1%'
or 
  title LIKE '%key2%' 
or 
  title LIKE '%key3%' 
or 
  title LIKE '%key4%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
    count(if(vid between 1 and 25000, 1, 0)) as totalvideocnt
from
    video
where
    (title like '%key1%' or title like '%key2%' or title like '%key3%' or title like '%key4%')
```